# How to set title_create and button name in SonataAdminBundle?

Tags: symfony, sonata

I am using SonataAdminBundle and I don't know how to change my button name and my title_create when I make a Form. I think that is easy to do but I find nothing on the official documentation. I suppose than I have to change my config.yml.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define your own translations

```
//copied from profiler
Locale | Domain            |Times used | Message ID   | Message Preview
de     | SonataAdminBundle |    2      | title_create | Hinzufügen
```

assuming you use the new app structure, for german translation and using yaml:

create a file ${APP_ROOT}/translations/SonataAdminBundle.de.yml  with

```
title_create: your own create title
```

for a format other than yaml see 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-resources

don't forget to clear your cache after you created the file!

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```